# Delphi 2007 Pro - Best way to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, components

I usually use Delphi-targeted databases for most of my work (NexusDB typically, lately), but still have bad memories of how painfully slow connecting (and posting) to MS Access was via ADO.  I have a new project that may need to target MS SQL Server.  For D2007 Pro, what is the best way to connect to MS SQL Server?  (Third party components = fine, if that's the best route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devart offer [components](http://www.devart.com/sdac/) and [dbExpress drivers](http://www.devart.com/dbx/) for accessing SQL Server databases.  The also have [UniDAC](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) which supports other databases as well.

Da-soft [AnyDac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) supports SQL Server and other databases.

Bob Swart has published [Delphi for Win32 VCL Database Development](http://www.lulu.com/content/1165954) on Lulu, if you need any help.

Answer (score 6):

The TADOConnection really isn't that bad. Access was never intended to be a production RDBMS. ADO works much faster with SQL Server than with Access. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225048 for some of the reasons why.

Comment: if using TADO* without using databound controls, always call DisableControls before opening - it can be much faster.

Comment: p.s. It can be better to create your own subclasses, calling DisableControls in the constructor.

Comment: I use TADO* with TClientDatasets to connect MS SQL Server, no problem at all. All Access projects I've done was a maintenance project, which finished sometime ago.....

Answer (score 3):

The [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) offers great feature set and performance, as simplifies development of the database applications. AnyDAC supports MS SQL Server, MS Access and much more.

Answer (score 2):

The [UniDac](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) Component from DevArt / Corelab is your best option 
It offers fast performance and you can talk to a number of differrent databases

Answer (score 2):

I always recommended DevArt db components fro their performance and reliability.

You can choose between [SDAC](http://www.devart.com/sdac)(for direct access to sql server) or [UniDac](http://www.devart.com/unidac) (direct access to Sql server, Oracle, MySql,PostgreSql and Interbase/firebird)

if you don't require the advanced components that access specific features of sql server like TMSChangeNotification, TMSTransaction or TMSServiceBroker, then you can go with [UniDac](http://www.devart.com/unidac) so your application will be designed to work with multiple databases.

Answer (score 1):

I use ADO to connect to Sql Server since Delphi 7 and it always worked great